# The goal is to read two strings into 2 different variables. Then we count the number of "C" in each string and output the result

Tags: c, string, for-loop, if-statement

Here is what I did:

```
int main ()
{
  int count = 0;
  int i, j;
  char firstLine[10000000];
  char secondLine[10000000];
  scanf("%s", firstLine);
  scanf("%s", secondLine);
  
  for (i=0;i<10000000;i++) {
      if (firstLine[i] == 'C') {count++;}
  }
  for (j=0;j<10000000;j++) {
      if (secondLine[j] == 'C') {count++;}
  }
  printf("%d", count);
  
  
  return 0;
}
```

I think it makes sense but there is some sort of segmentation error according to my compiler. What am I missing?

For example, an input of AB
BBAAB should yield an output of 0.

Comment: 10000000? That's a lot, especially if it's a local array on the stack. And you are scanning it all, even if the input is just "AB". Also, I think you need two different counts instead if two different iteration variables.

Comment: I reduced the size of the char but it doesnt work as expected. For example, it outputs 1 more than the actual result, that is, if there is no "C", it outputs 1 instead of zero. Also, I took your advice and used 1 iteration variable and 2 different count variables.

Comment: Do you print both counts? Do you initialize both counts? (That advice was, because the question says "in each string".) You also need to stop scanning when the string ends, that is when you encounter the null terminator `'\0'`. Otherwise, you scan the garbage values beyond that null terminator, which may contain spurious C's.

Comment: Note that using `scanf("%s", firstline)` reads up to the first white space — it is not guaranteed to read a line. To read lines, use `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`. The maximum default stack size on many Linux and Unix machines is 8 MiB; on Windows, it is 1 MiB.  Trying to allocate 20 MiB on stack will fail on most systems unless you take special steps to configure a bigger-than-normal stack size.  You need to establish how much data was read into the strings; scanning over the whole variable is wrong.  You don't need both variables (you could read once, count once, read again, count again).

Comment: What should be the output from ABC CDC?  Is 3 the expected output?  That's probably what you'll get (unless there are stray C's in the strings, which were not initialized — as I hinted at in my previous comment, you should stop counting at the null marking the end of the strings).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how does that look like in code?

Comment: How many different ways do you want to do it?  There are many possibilities that work, and many, many more that don't.  Since you don't use the lines after you read them, there's no need to store the lines; you could simply read each character and count the occurrences of `C` before you reach EOF or the second newline, whichever comes sooner.  If your homework says "read two lines into two variables, then count", then that's what you'd better do.  I can't see (and don't really want to see) your homework instructions, so I can't tell what's best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
#define BUF_MAX 100

int main ()
{
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
    char firstLine[BUF_MAX];
    char secondLine[BUF_MAX];

    fgets(firstLine,BUF_MAX,stdin);
    for (int i = 0; firstLine[i] != 0; ++i)
        if (firstLine[i] == 'C') ++count1;
    fgets(secondLine,BUF_MAX,stdin);
    for (int i = 0; secondLine[i] != 0; ++i)
        if (secondLine[i] == 'C') ++count2;
    printf("String 1 has %d C's\n", count1);
    printf("String 2 has %d C's\n", count2);
    return 0;
}
```

The BUF_MAX sets the maximum size of each line buffer, which I chose to be 100 (99 characters + the terminating null). If this isn't enough, make it bigger... say 500. But 10,000,000 is absurd... that could be the complete text of all of the Harry Potter books combined, or perhaps the complete works of Shakespeare!
The for loops continue as long as the character in the string is non-zero, i.e. until the terminating null character is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop counting (`break;`) when you find a 0-terminator in your lines.

At the moment, you are going through an uninitialized garbage looking for random `C`